# Main actor who does not know he is in the movie

Tags: identify-this-movie

I have been trying to remember the name of a movie, made probably in the last 10-15 years.

The plot, set in Hollywood, is about a director who is filming a movie where the main actor is not aware that he (or she, I can't remember) is the main actor of the movie. He is not even aware that he participates in the movie. Most of the crew is also unaware of this.

The movie goes on the director hiding this from the crew and creating situations where he can film the unknowingly actor in situations appropriate for his story.

Anyone knows this movie?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds like [**Bowfinger**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0131325/) (1999):

> [image]
>
> When a desperate movie producer fails to get a major star for his bargain basement film, he decides to shoot the film secretly around him.

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bowfinger) has some more details

Answer (score 1):

It is a movie with Jim Carey. I believe it is called [*The Truman Show*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120382/).  When he is born, he automatically was in a TV show and when he gets older, he eventually realizes this.

Comment: Welcome to [movies.se]. Given that another answer has already been accepted by the OP as the correct answer to his question, I cannot see how this answer could contribute anything to the matter anymore.

Comment: +1 It does match the OP's description and it might help other future visitors (like me) that read this thread.